# There is no result type defined for type 'tiles' mapped with name 'sessionTimeout'

Tags: struts2

I am migrating Struts1 to Struts2 web project. Struts2 project will use spring, tiles2 and bootstrap. Now it has below problems. I am using struts2-core-2.5.1 of jdk 1.7. I tried a lot of combination of tiles version 2/3 with others jar version or absent and search in google. Finally it still has below exception and run the program. Please let me know if you need me to provide more information.

```
 ERROR org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Dispatcher initialization failed
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to load configuration.
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70) ~[struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:897) ~[struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:437) ~[struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:478) [struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75) [struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63) [struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:374) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) [com.oracle.css.weblogic.security.wls_7.1.0.0.jar:CSS 7.1 0.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.initFilter(FilterManager.java:125) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.loadFilter(FilterManager.java:88) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.preloadFilters(FilterManager.java:68) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1844) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2876) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:823) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:73) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:226) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:418) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:210) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:118) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:78) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1017) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:388) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:430) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) [weblogic.server.merged.jar:12.1.3.0.0]
Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: There is no result type defined for type 'tiles' mapped with name 'sessionTimeout'.  Did you mean 'tiles'?
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.buildResults(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:730) ~[struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadGlobalResults(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:915) ~[struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:545) ~[struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:311) ~[struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:108) ~[struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:187) ~[struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67) ~[struts2-core-2.5.1.jar:2.5.1]
    ... 70 more
```

configuration:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
    <struts>
    <package name="testAwip" extends="struts-default">

        <result-types>
          <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
        </result-types>

        <action name="logon" class="logonAction">
            <result name="sessionTimeout"  type="tiles">.logon.LogonForm</result>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" metadata-complete="true" version="2.5">

<context-param>
       <param-name>
          tilesDefinitions
       </param-name>
       <param-value>
          /WEB-INF/tiles.xml
       </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
          </filter-class>
          <init-param>
                <param-name>CharacterEncoding</param-name>
                <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
            </init-param>

</filter>
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: ...how was your upgrade strategy so far/what have you changed? can we see the "struts config", which fails with missing result 'tiles'?

Comment: I have tried the answers but failed. (1) I have struts-core-2.5.1, struts-spring-plugin-2.1.6, struts-tiles-2.0.11.2. with some others jars. The errors are still the same. (2) Checked struts.xml are exists under web-inf/classes. (3) Tried tiles3 with struts2-tiles3-plugin also, also the same error.  Actually previously I used only struts2 and spring, it is successfully without adding struts2-tiles-plugin. After adding tiles feature with changing struts.xml file, it causes this problem. If I not used tiles type, it is Success.

Comment: Now I will use struts2+tiles3 with checking example in https://github.com/apache/struts-examples/tree/master/tiles

Comment: It is solved when I follow the struts2-tiles and other jar versions as in the github link sample tiles pom. Thanks

Comment: It is working under my developed computer with weblogic 12.1.3 setup locally for development. When deployed to UAT weblogic 12.1.3, it has error: Cannot find definition named '.logon.LogonForm'
File: org/apache/tiles/impl/mgmt/CachingTilesContainer.java
Line number: 123.

Comment: I find some hints on the web. Will try to see and I think it may be small issue.